# Simple form with pixel manipulation with opengl in linux

Tags: c, linux, opengl, graphics

i want to create a 800X600 window that just show some circle and be able to manipulate pixels of the form every milisecond and show the result to the user. there is no interaction between user and form(no click, no dblclick,…) it just shows some circles with one color and lines with different pixel colors(each line may have different pixel colors)
also i want to be able to change the coordination system, i mean change it from top-left to the center of the window. could anyone help me do that with some sample code? links? tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL doesn't have a built-in circle function, but it does have line functions, and you can simulate a circle using polygons. To draw lines, you can do something like this:

```
glBegin (GL_LINES);
// First line segment
glVertex2f (x0, y0);
glVertex2f (x1, y1);
// Second line segment
glVertex2f (x2, y2);
glVertex2f (x3, y3);
glEnd ();
```

To draw a circle, you can write a loop to draw a triangle fan. Something like:

```
glBegin (GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
// Center point
glVertex2f (cx, cy);
for (segment = 0; segment < maxSegments; segment++)
{
    double angle = delta * segment;
    double x = cx + cos (angle) * radius;
    double y = cy + sin (angle) * radius;
    glVertex2f (x, y);
}
glEnd ();
```

In this case, delta is `2 * pi / maxSegments`, and maxSegments is the number of segments you want in your circle approximation.